# How SSRS report are generated once subscribed, Serially or Parallel

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

Suppose we  have created only one schedule to generate 100 reports.

Once the  schedule is subscribed , how the report will be generated ?

Will all 100 reports generated simultaneously ?

or

Reports will be generated sequentially one by one ?

P.S . I am not talking about multiple subscription.I am talking about reports in only one subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need a little more clarity, are you talking about one subscription running multiple reports or multiple subscriptions?

This isn't really an answer, but I am 4 points too short to comment yet.

This article has some information. Basically it depends how your RS server is set up. Mine is set pretty low. I never see more than one subscription/report running at a time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157273.aspx

For my data driven subscriptions I can see the reports run one at a time during testing.

---update--

MaxActiveReqForOneUser value from rsreportserver.config  defines number of report running inparallel . default value is 20

P.S. Subscribed reports run in parallel and maximum report running in parallel are 20 by default.

Comment: I am talking about one subscription running multiple reports

Comment: I am pretty sure the article about queues above still applies. Like I said, I can see my subscriptions running one report at a time. It will say, 25 processed of 100 total, 2 errors.